# Android on virtualBox gets stuck after idle

Tags: android, virtualbox, android-x86

I am running a VirtualBox with android-x86 (as a replacement for the ultra-slow AVD emulator).
Its a Linux VirtualBox running android 4.0, on a Windows 7 Host.
The machine boots up and everything works fine, but if i leave the machine idle for less than 5 min, i can't perform any action - all the menus,buttons,etc are unresponsive although the android clock is changing, and i can go to command (alt + F1) and back to gui (alt + F7).
Has anyone came across this phenomenon or has an idea what goes wrong here?

Answer (score 25):

I was able to get back to the screen by clicking ACPI shutdown menu(HOST + H)

Comment: This answer is essentially the same as the one by Bruno Volpato, which was posted months before yours.

Answer (score 18):

It is pretty simple. Just hold ESC + [MENU](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Menu_key) (A key between right-alt and right-ctrl) and the machine will wake up.

Answer (score 10):

I had this problem today and couldn't solve with any keys provided by the documents.

Android will resume if you try to close the VirtualBox window, and when asked, select to send shutdown signal instead of forced shutdown.

Answer (score 9):

Try disabling the sleep time to never. You can find it under settings.

Here are something users need to know

1. You can only use ESC, Menu, left, right, up and down keys to wake up the system.
2. To wake up the system ,you have to hold the keys mentioned above for at least 1 second.
3. You can push menu key when keyguard screen showing up to unlock screen.
4. You can use mouse to turn the wheel on the keyguard screen to unlock screen.

Source : http://old.android-x86.org/documents/how-to-wake-up-machine

Comment: +_1 for link to the documentation

Comment: Link changed to https://www.android-x86.org/documentation/wake_machine.html

Answer (score 5):

open the "dev tools" app / developer options / stay awake.

Comment: I didnt have this option under the dev tools app

Comment: If you get the message about enabling developer options first, go to the settings menu -> scroll down to "System" ->"About Tablet" -> scroll down to "Build Number" -> click on build number over and over until a countdown shows up, once complete you'll have enabled the developer options.